# Ubuntu Compatibility Mode

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, compatibility

A coworker and I are using Ubuntu VMs to do some development. I am using 20.04 and he is using 18.04. We are using a tool named `ceedling` for automated testing of our code base. To the best of my ability it seems the only difference in our tools is the version of Ubuntu.

My question is, is there a way to run the `ceedling` program as if I was using Ubuntu 18.04, similar to the Windows Compatibility run?

Comment: Probably not. Which "incompatibilities" do you want to avoid? Ask the developers of `ceedling`.

Comment: `To the best of my ability it seems the only difference in our tools is the version of Ubuntu` -- What difference did you encounter?

Comment: It turns out I misunderstood a part of Ubuntu. I suppose when you perform apt-get install this does not necessarily get the latest version. The ceedling library is not in error. The issue is a change in a header file changed from 18.04 to 20.04

Comment: Did you read the Release Notes for 20.04 `https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no software that runs exactly the same way as Windows compatibility mode in Ubuntu. The closest thing to Windows compatibility mode in Ubuntu is to run your software (ceedling) in an Ubuntu guest OS in a virtual machine.